# Is the genitive case used with comparatives?

Tags: сравнительная-степень

In the Russian sentence

> Маленькие дети ходят медленнее взрослых

why is взрослых in the genitive case?

Is the genitive case always used in comparatives for the thing that is forming the basis of comparison?

Comment: I tried to remember some poems by a classical poet with a comparative construction and my memory immediately suggested *Гарун бежал быстрее лани* (genitive case), *быстрей, чем заяц* (in this example, this is the nominative case, but the accusative would also be appropriate here) *от орла*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this particular construct, the comparative adjective (медленнее) should be followed by a genitive. However, there is an alternative construct that uses the nominative:

> Ма́ленькие де́ти хо́дят ме́дленнее, чем взро́слые.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to use the comparatives in Russian:

1. Analytically, using the relative pronoun *чем*: *маленькие дети ходят быстрее, чем взрослые*. In these constructs, the comparand and the basis have to agree in case: *я люблю маленьких детей больше, чем взрослых*.

   Note that there are some edge cases when both the comparand and the verb the comparative modifies are omitted: *ты найдёшь кого-то богаче, чем я* (= *ты найдёшь кого-то, кто богаче, чем я*). In this case, the basis has to agree with this omitted comparand.
2. Synthetically. This is what your example uses. As you correctly mentioned, *чем* is omitted and the basis is always put into the genitive.

It works exactly the same way in Latin. They either use *quam* plus the basis in the same case as the comparand, or put the basis into the ablative (which has merged with the genitive in Slavic languages).